# Polling AJAX client for P2P file sharing website

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, recursion, ajax

I have this function:

```
function Filer() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Pages/Handlers/filecheckerhandler.ashx',
            data: { id: GetMyId(), sid: GetSessionId() },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "true") {
                    window.open('/Pages/Handlers/livesharehandler.ashx?id=' + GetMyId() + '&sid=' + GetSessionId(), '_self');
                }
            },
            global: false
        });
        Filer();
    }, 2000)
}
Filer();
```

Basically, my website allows for peer to peer file sharing online. What this does is checks for files and if it is present the file will be downloaded **and** the file will be deleted from the server.

The function is recursive as you can see. This is making a lot of requests.

But my function is making a lot of requests which is making the site slow. What can be done?

Comment: You should post all of your code here for review. With the little information you've given I can only suggest that you looked at websockets.

Comment: From the code that you're showing, nothing can be done. If you want help, you'd have to show your actual code. From the code you've got there, only one request is being made, and it's going to an invalid URL and it's doing nothing when it succeeds.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I come from SO background, so I thought I should give a minimal example. I've edited it with my actual code.

Comment: SO != CR. Here you post your working code which you want to review. In SO you should post a minimal example of the problem you have since your full code could be useless. -- Anyway, why this function is recursive?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno it is recursive because I need it to repeatedly check for file which might be uploaded by another user and download it immediately and delete it on the server

Comment: This is a marginal Code Review question.  The performance problem is primarily due to the design of your application, not just this function.  You would be better off asking on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), stating both how the app currently works _and_ what the goal of the application is, in a way that is open to a complete redesign.

Comment: Nevertheless, I've reopened the question for Code Review.

Answer (score 2):

You are polling `filecheckerhandler.ashx` regularly at two-second intervals. The fact that such polling is implemented using recursion, with `Filer()` calling itself, is irrelevant to your performance problem.  You could improve the client code by using `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`, but the overall system performance will be just as bad.

There are only three strategies to improve system performance:

1. Lengthen the polling interval.  Especially if no activity has occurred recently, activity is less likely in the near future, so the polling interval could be adaptive.
2. Improve the efficiency of `filecheckerhandler.ashx`.  The constraining factor is probably load on the server, rather than load on the client, so any efficiency gains on the server would likely make an impact.
3. Improve the efficiency of the communication protocol.  Each AJAX request is essentially a new HTTP request, with the only optimization being possible HTTP keep-alive, which might avoid the TCP handshake.  Consider a technique that is more suitable for client-to-server notifications, such as [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).